# Prove for some $\theta$ in $(0,\pi/2)$, $\sin⁡{\theta}-\cos^3{\theta}+\theta^7=1$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Prove that there is some number $\theta$ in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$ such that $\sin⁡{\theta}-\cos^3{\theta}+\theta^7=1$.

How to prove?

Comment: What have you tried? e.g. did you use the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: Hint: $\theta=0$ leads to $\text{LHS}<1$ and $\theta=\frac\pi2$ leads to $\text{LHS}>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(\theta) = \theta^7+\sin (\theta)-\cos ^3(\theta)-1$.

We have $f(0)=-2$ and $f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^7$.

So for the intermediate value theorem there must be at least a value $\theta^*$ where $f(\theta^*)=0$, that is $\theta^*\approx 0.895881$.

Comment: @cosmo5 Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much